# PHP creating dynamic arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, dynamic, foreach

I am trying to make dynamic arrays from the below loop

```
foreach( $all_arrays as $option => $all_arrays_vals ){

   foreach( $all_arrays_vals as $all_arrays_vals_key => $value){

          //Dynamic arrays goes here

         print 'options = '.$option .' values = '.$value.'<br />';

       }
  }
```

the above code generates the output

```
options = Type values = GOLD
options = Purity values = 75.0+%
options = Purity values = 58.33+%
options = Purity values = 37.5k
options = Model values = Quantity
options = Model values = 1.0mm
options = Model values = 1.2mm

I need every same "option" an array, e.g 

type = {GOLD};

purity = {75.0+% , 58.33+% , 37.5k};

Model = {Quantity , 1.0mm , 1.2mm};
```

In this particular example it has three "Options"(type, purity, model) which I want to create arrays. Every time these loops run it might have different number of arrays (OPTIONS).
Hope I have explained the problem

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save those items in a new `array`  while checking if the `index` is already `set`

```
    $array = array();        

    foreach( $all_arrays as $option => $all_arrays_vals ){

       foreach( $all_arrays_vals as $all_arrays_vals_key => $value){

            if(!isset($array[$option])){

                $array[$option] = array();

            }

            $array[$option][] = $value;

       }

    }

    var_dump($array);
```